# How to read an unstructured excel sheet into R and clean it to be used in Shiny?

Tags: r, excel, shiny

Our excel sheet is formatted in a strange manner. Some headers are located in the first row, others are located in either the 2nd,3rd, or 4th row. Beneath the 4th row is the first subset of data we want to generate graphs from, there are multiple subsets as you go down the excel sheet. Each of these subsets is separated by an empty row. The first column is dedicated to the name of the source of the data. For example in the first column and 5th row, there is a label called "communications" and to the right is the data. The rows in the first column under "communications" are empty until the next label. We need to be able to read the separate subsets in shiny to generate individual graphs. How do you recommend we go about this? We are fairly new to R and are lost on where to go.

Comment: is it always consistently weird?

Comment: No, the only weird part is the first headers. After that, the subsets are almost consistently formatted

Comment: You should provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). R expects clean, rectangular data. Probably best to just reformat and save as a plain text csv and then import into R.

Comment: Part of the project requirements is that the excel file can not be directly manipulated, everything must be done through R

Comment: reproducible example of the spreadsheet?